# How to use pd.read_excel without changing values or format

Tags: json, pandas

I have this data in Excel File

[image]

When read with this logic,

```
df = pd.read_excel(xls_file_path)
# Convert DataFrame to JSON
json_data = df.to_json(orient='records')
print(json_data)

[{"Name":"Deepak Kalindi","Employee ID":101,"Joining Date":1704153600000,"Leaving Date":null,"Monthly Salary":12000,"Number of full days":27,"Number of half days":2.5,"Number of leaves":1.5,"OT (full Day)":3,"OT (half Day)":2}]
```

How to get Joining Date as "02-01-2024" in JSON string?

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341), post the text itself and use the formatting tools like [code](/editing-help#code) or [tables](/editing-help#tables).

Comment: Also, if only the date is important, you can remove most of the other data. I'd leave just the name and employee ID, personally. For reference see [mre] and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Answer (score 0):

Try with `date_format=iso`, see [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)

```
json_data = df.to_json(orient='records', date_format='iso')
print(json_data)
```

Output:

```
[{"Name":"XYZ","Date":"2024-01-02T00:00:00.000Z"}]
```

Also, you can force your date columns to be string, which will give you the exact output but depending on your end use-case might not be appropriate:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(str)
json_data = df.to_json(orient='records')
print(json_data)
```

Print:

```
[{"Name":"XYZ","Date":"2024-01-02"}]
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that that's not the format OP wants, but it's unambiguous while OP's format isn't.

Comment: You can add `date_unit='s'` to skip the unnecessary milliseconds. It'd be nice if it could go to days, but I guess Pandas doesn't do that.

Comment: @wjandrea that is true, I've added another solution for what OP wants but the question is a bit ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `dt.strftime`:

```
jdata = (df.assign(**{'Joining Date': df['Joining Date'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')})
           .to_json(orient='records', indent=4))
```

Output:

```
>>> jdata
[
    {
        "Name":"Deepak Kalindi",
        "Employee ID":101,
        "Joining Date":"02-01-2024",
        "Leaving Date":null,
        "Monthly Salary":12000,
        "Number of full days":27,
        "Number of half days":2.5,
        "Number of leaves":1.5,
        "OT (full Day)":3,
        "OT (half Day)":2
    }
]
```